# What makes random variables exchangeable and what is implied by exchangeability?

Tags: probability

Consider a $d$-dimensional random vector$\ X=(X_j)$. $\ X$ is called exchangeable if $\ (X_1,\ldots,X_d)\mathrel{\overset d =} ({X_{{j_1}}},\ldots,X_{j_d})$ for any permutation$\ j_1,\ldots, j_d$. If$\ X_j$ are iid,$\ X$ is exchangeable. The converse is false (correct me if I'm wrong). What can we say about just identically distributed $\ X_j$? What can we say about $\ X_j$ if we know that$\ X$ is exchangeable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple and rather general way to build an exchangeable random vector $X=(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is to start from an i.i.d. sequence $(Y_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ and to define, for every $k$, $X_k=\Phi(U,Y_k)$, where $U$ is a random variable independent on $(Y_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ and $\Phi$ a measurable function.

And, in some (loose) sense, this is the only way... as shown by Diaconis and Freedman for finite sequences, using mixtures of urn sequences rather than mixtures of i.i.d. sequences, and earlier, by [de Finetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Finetti%27s_theorem) for infinite sequences.

Comment: For finite sequences one has to be careful. In that case, one obtains a mixture of the so-called urn-sequences, rather than of i.i.d. sequences.

Comment: Does this mean any exchangeable sequence can be written this way? And that to prove a sequence is exchangeable we just have to show it can be represented this way?

Comment: @Arun Every such sequence is exchangeable. The converse is not so clear.

Answer (score 21):

Exchangeability implies being identically distributed, but not the reverse. 
An exchangeable sequence has extra symmetry.

For instance, below I've written the joint mass function of $(X,Y)$,
 where $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\{0,1,2\}$. Checking the marginals shows that 
they are identically distributed, but 
$$\mathbb{P}(X=0,Y=2)=1/7\neq \mathbb{P}(Y=0,X=2)=0/7.$$
 That is, the *random variables* $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, but the *random vectors* $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ don't.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
x\backslash y&0&1&2\cr
\hline
0&0/7&1/7&1/7\\
1&2/7&0/7&1/7\\
2&0/7&2/7&0/7\\
\end{array}
$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/why-does-this-expected-value-simplify-as-shown/66478#66478) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56706/probability-for-pairing-up/56751#56751) for further applications of exchangeability.

Answer (score 11):

If the converse were true, then "i.i.d." and exchangeability would be the same thing, and instead of having a separate concept, "exchangeability", one would have a theorem saying there are these two equivalent characterizations of the concept.

Exchangeability is stronger than identical distribution.  Note that $X_1\overset{d}{=}X_{j_1}$, so these two are identically distributed, and $j_1$ could be any index.

A couple of important examples of exchangeability:

- First choose $p\in(0,1)$ randomly and suppose it's uniformly distributed, then let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ be conditionally i.i.d. given $p$, with $X_1 = \left.\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability }p \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1-p  \end{cases} \right\}$.  Then $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$, which are conditionally independent given the value of $p$, are not independent.  To see that, suppose you observe the first 20 of these are equal to $1$.  That makes it quite probable that $p$ is near $1$, so that it's likely that $X_{21}$ is equal to $1$.  But by symmetry in the way the distribution was described, they are exchangeable.  De Finetti's theorem says every infinitely long exchangeable sequence is a mixture of i.i.d. sequences in this manner (but the distribution of $p$ need not be uniform).
- Suppose an urn contains $10$ red and $15$ green marbles, and $X_k$ the number of red marbles on the $k$th draw **without** replacement, for $k=1,\ldots,12$.  If you see $10$ red marbles in the first $10$ draws, then you *know* the $11$th one will be green, so they're not independent.  But it's not hard to show they're exchangeable.  Unlike the previous example, this one *cannot* be extended to an infinitely long sequence of exchangeable random variables.

You can't say anything about the distribution of $X_j$ if you know it's part of an exchangeable sequence, since any distribution at all can be in that role.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc : $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are CONDITIONALLY independent given the value of $p.$ Yes, you can have a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables, but here you need to take into account that $p$ is also random and that the independence is conditional.

Comment: If a Bayesian gets an IID bernoulli sequence and tries to infer p, he will hypothesize a prior over p and carry on. Does this all of a sudden make the IID sequence conditionally independent? Is this something philosophical or are we discussing something mathematical?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc : Just math. If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are conditionally i.i.d. $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ given $p,$ then $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are _not_ marginally_ independent, but are positively correlated.

Comment: Regarding the second example: "Suppose an urn contains 10 red and 15 green marbles, and $X_k$ the number of red marbles on the k-th position draw without replacement". How can we show that $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ are exchangeable?

Comment: @ady : There are $\dbinom{15} 5 = 252$ sequences of $0$s and $1$s. All are equally likely to be the one that occurs because all $15! = 1307674368000$ sequences of $15$ marbles are equally probable. $\qquad$